# Jlabel color change

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, jlabel

I tried to change the color of a jlabel in java netbeans

I need a code to change the jLabel color

Like:

```
JLabel.SetColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Simply the code is

```
jLabel1.setForeground(Color.red);
```